# Is there a way to load-balance the eureka server (spring boot)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

We are using spring boot with eureka for service discovery. Need to understand that Can we use multiple instance of spring boot eureka server behind the load balancer?

Comment: You can register multiple Eureka server peers, which can be seen [in the documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-eureka-server.html#spring-cloud-eureka-server-peer-awareness). Does that answer your question or are you looking for something else?

Comment: Eureka wasn't designed to be behind a load balancer. Each client needs to know about all eureka server peers.

Comment: I also had the same doupt thanks @spencergibb your comment is actual answer to the question. we can achieve resilience through peer awareness but not load balancing if I am wrong please correct me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using [peer awareness](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_peer_awareness). They will synchronise with each other and you can communicate with any of the instances through the load balancer.

Comment: how can this be right answer @jeff peer awareness is for resilience not for load balancing